# An inequality for the $W^{k,1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $Q=(0,1)^n$, $u\in W^{k,1}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ do we have an inequality $\sum\limits_{|a|\leq k}\|\frac{\partial ^a}{\partial x^a}w\|_{L^1(Q)}\leq C\|w\|_{L^1(Q)}+C\sum\limits_{|a|=k}\|\frac{\partial ^a}{\partial x^a}w\|_{L^1(Q)}$.
It is better, if we have $\sum\limits_{|a|\leq k}\|\frac{\partial ^a}{\partial x^a}w\|_{L^1(Q)}\leq C\sum\limits_{|a|=k}\|\frac{\partial ^a}{\partial x^a}w\|_{L^1(Q)}$. The first inequality somehow follows by the Sobolev embedding, but I dont know why.

Comment: The second inequality is certainly false since it does not hold for constant functions

Comment: For the first claim: Argue by contradiction and use the compact embedding $W^{k,1}(Q)\hookrightarrow W^{k-1,1}(Q)$.

Comment: This is a standard proof for such inequalities, see e.g. the argument in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3934501/sobolev-inequalities-for-w1-sq-and-w2-sq?rq=1